# php encode string and vice-versa

Tags: php, encryption, encode

I have some entities(objects), each one having an id(unique) and a name.
When i want to display oneof these , i have a url like www.domain.com/view/key:xxx.
The key is just the id of the entity encoded with base64_encode, so it's not straightforward from the url what the id is.

What i'm trying to do now (due to the projects specifications) is have the key contain only numbers and letters (base64_encode provides a result like `eyJpZCI6IjM2In0=` or `eyJpZCI6IjM2In0%3D` after url encode).

Is there a simple alternative to this? It's not a high-security issue - there are many ways the id can be revealed -, i just need to have a key that contains only letters and numbers that is produced by the entity ID (maybe in combination with its name) that can be decoded to give me the ID back.

All different encode methods i've found can contain special characters as well.
Any help here?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer doesn't really apply encryption, but since your question was tagged with encoding as well ...

Since PHP 5 you can use `bin2hex`:

```
$s = base64_decode('eyJpZCI6IjM2In0=');
echo bin2hex($s);
```

Output:

```
7b226964223a223336227d
```

To decode:

```
$s = hex2bin($data);
```

Or:

```
$s = pack('H*', $data);
```

Btw, if the `id` is sensitive you might want to consider tamper proofing it as an alternative to full-blown encryption.

---

Forgot to mention how you can make `base64` encoded data URL safe:

```
function base64_url_encode($input)
{
    return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64_url_decode($input)
{
    return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}
```

Comment: @dynamic of course, but you can always use `pack('H*', $str);` as the alternative for php < 5.3

Comment: Is php.net down for anyone else? I'm trying to look at the hex2bin function. and yeah Jack, thanks.

Comment: @dynamic yeah, i've been using `us2.php.net` for the time being :(

Comment: Same for me ... You can use the mirrrors like http://de.php.net though (even if you're not from Germany :-))

Answer (score 0):

There are many PHP encoding/decoding functions.
You can find a lot [here](http://www.crypo.com/tools/index.php) and [here](http://hackers.co.id/esab-46.php).

Alternatively just get rid of the = at the end of the base64_encode and add it in the PHP code for base64_decode to find the ID.

Comment: Can't just get rid of the '=', it may have more than one, and then i will not be able to know how many '=' there where...

Comment: @CrisDeBlonde: if you make your ID a fixed length, say by padding the ID on left with leading zeros, then you will always know how many '=' there will be on the end and you can remove them.